# Given a geometric Brownian motion, obtain a recurrence relation for moment $\mathbb{E}X_k^q$ and deduce $\mathbb{E}_k^q=\alpha^k(ah^{1/2},q)$

Tags: brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

I am really confused about a step in the solution of this problem. I would really appreciate it if someone could explain to me what is in bold below. Part A is OK, but I don't understand something in part B. Thanks in advance!

**Question:** Consider the geometric Brownian motion equation
$$dX=aXdW,\quad X(0)=1,\quad a>0.$$
**A)** Write down the Euler-Maruyama scheme for this equation.

**B)** Obtain a recurrence relation for the moment $\mathbb{E}X_k^q$ and deduce that $$\mathbb{E}X_k^q=\alpha^k(ah^{1/2},q),$$
where $$\alpha(a,q)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(1+ax\right)^q e^{-x^2/2}dx$$

**Solutions:**

**A)**
$$X_{k+1}=X_k+aX_k\Delta W_k=(1+a\Delta W_k)X_k$$
**B)**
Taking the $q$th power and expectation of the Euler-Maruyama scheme for this equation gives
$$\mathbb{E}X_{k+1}^q=\mathbb{E}\left(1+a\Delta W_k\right)^q\mathbb{E}X_k^q$$
Using the initial condition, we find that

**Now, this is what confuses me. How does my professor use the initial condition $X(0)=1$?**
$$\mathbb{E}X_k^q=\left(\mathbb{E}(1+a\Delta W_k)^q\right)^k=C^k,$$
where
$$C=\mathbb{E}(1+a\Delta W_k)^q=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi h}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(1+ax)^qe^{-x^2/(2h)}dx.$$

Introducing the change of variables $x\mapsto h^{1/2}x$ leads to $C=\alpha(ah^{1/2},q)$ and hence to the result.

Comment: I guess your question is : why the expectation of the product is the product of the expectations ? The answer is $\Delta W_k$ is independent to $X_k$ ( which is the "independent increment" fact )!

Comment: I know that the expectation of the product is the product of the expectations... What I don't know is what $X_k^q$ is in this case, if we use the Euler-Maruyama scheme for the equation.

Answer (score 0):

> Taking the $q$th power and expectation of the Euler-Maruyama scheme for this equation gives
> $$\mathbb{E}X_{k+1}^q=\mathbb{E}\left(1+a\Delta W_k\right)^q\mathbb{E}X_k^q$$
> Using the initial condition, we find that
> **Now, this is what confuses me. How does my professor use the initial condition $X(0)=1$?**
> $$\mathbb{E}X_k^q=\left(\mathbb{E}(1+a\Delta W_k)^q\right)^k=C^k,$$
> where
> $$C=\mathbb{E}(1+a\Delta W_k)^q=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi h}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(1+ax)^qe^{-x^2/(2h)}dx.$$

So here we obtain a recursion relation for $y_{k}:=\mathbb{E}X_k^q$

$$y_{k+1}=y_{k}\mathbb{E}\left(1+a\Delta W_k\right)^q$$

and so by solving it we obtain

$$y_{k+1}=\prod_{i=1}^{k}\mathbb{E}\left(1+a\Delta W_i\right)^q$$

$$=\left(\mathbb{E}\left(1+a\Delta W_1\right)^q\right)^{k},$$

where we used the stationarity of the increments $\Delta W_i\sim \Delta W_1$.